# CSS tabs have hover

Tags: html, css

I've a css problem on Chrome, When i click next tabs background image is not hide.

I've used ::after code is like that.

```
.paymentBank ::after {
    content: " ";

}
```

[Here][1] is live code. I've prepare screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your CSS change `.payactiveAddress ::after` to `.payactiveAddress::after`. You're currently applying the `::after` pseudo class to every child within `.payactiveAddress`.

Comment: @ErdalBakkal No worries, don' forget to accept the answer :).